# how to send JSON string to WCF using VBA

Tags: json, vba, wcf, xmlhttprequest

trying to send a POST to WCF services that accepts JSON string based on the website's JS. I had no luck buy just copy and paste the JSON string in an excel cell and use VBA's XMLHTTP60 to post. Always get bad data (status 400).
tried JSON string and JSON in cell doesn't work. I tried different JSON encoding doesn't seem to work either.
anyidea how I would post a JSON String to WCF?

My guess is somehow the VBA string loses its format during the request. Or different character code \ and : was send.

```
{"country":"{\"name\":\"USA\",\"population\":\"10000\"}\"}
{"country":"{"name":"USA","population":"10000"}"}
```

my VBA code

```
Sub test()

Dim XMLRequest As New MSXML2.XMLHTTP60
website = "URL"
postdata = thisworkbook.worksheets("Sheet1").range("A1").value   
XMLRequest.Open "POST", "webSite", False
XMLRequest.SetRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/json; charset=UTF-8"
XMLRequest.send postdata

end sub
```

However, I can use a browser console to send the AJAX with no problem.

```
var data=JSON.Stringify('{"country":"{"name":"USA","population":"10000"}"}');
$Ajax({
method: "POST",
URL: URL,
dataType:json,
contentType: "application/json; charset=UTF-8",
data:data,
cache: false
})
```

or I have no problem sending javascript in VBA via IE object

```
 IE.Document.parentWindow.execScript "ajax call","javascript"
```

but my ultimate goal is to bypass IE, since it is not stable especially controlling through VBA.

Comment: Try `postdata = "{""country"":{""name"":""USA"",""population"":""10000""}}"`. What's the value in `thisworkbook.worksheets("Sheet1").range("A1").value`?

Comment: `{"country":"{"name":"USA","population":"10000"}"}` doesn't seems like a valid JSON.

Comment: @Raymond Wu the data is what I copied in the browser debug console before it get JSON.Stringify. And its based on my memory. And the data in A1 is the first 2 line of code I posted {"country":"{\"name\":\"USA\",\"population\":\"10000\"}\"} and {"country":"{"name":"USA","population":"10000"}"}, I tried them separately

Comment: Pasting that JSON to an editor prompts an [error](https://jsoneditoronline.org/#left=cloud.5834c8a72fcb4e9d988b866f5c9ef9d5) though.

Comment: @Raymond Wu I will try a JSON editor tomorrow. But this is pretty much copy and paste of browser request data. Since I typed from my memory, I might miss something.

Comment: For sending JSON strings to WCF, you can refer to this article: https://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Post-JSON-data-to-REST-WCF-Service-using-jQuery-AJAX-in-ASPNet.aspx